# Xubuntu 20.04 delayed action of Suspend on pressing Sleep button

Tags: suspend, power-management, xfce

I have set the Xfce **Power Management General > Buttons** in my Xubuntu 20.04 system to Suspend "when the sleep button is pressed".

When I click the Suspend button in the dialog called up by the power button, I immediately get a message about disconnection from the network, but it seems about 30 seconds before the machine actually goes to sleep.

How do I reduce this delay?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in screensaver, of all things.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-screensaver/+bug/1885444
https://gitlab.xfce.org/apps/xfce4-screensaver/-/issues/45

related to: https://gitlab.xfce.org/apps/xfce4-screensaver/-/issues/55
and: [Disable screen locking with xubuntu 20.04 and lightdm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246378/disable-screen-locking-with-xubuntu-20-04-and-lightdm)
the solution at the last link solved it for me, even though I don't have lightdm or lightlocker installed. However, you'll no longer have a screensaver or automated suspend action, and if you try to set those everything goes back to the 30 second delay and you will get a screen lock, or possibly two!

Answer (score 0):

Run in terminal:

```
sudo apt install xfce4-screensaver- xscreensaver
```

Log out and back in to session and then it should work better with good old xscreensaver.