# Disable screen locking with xubuntu 20.04 and lightdm

Tags: xubuntu, lightdm, lock-screen, light-locker

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and then installed `xubuntu-core`. When prompted, I chose lightdm as my login manager. I then disabled everything I could find related to screen locking, but I still have to enter my password after the screen goes off.
Is there some crazy hidden setting I am missing?

I realize I could remove lightlocker, but why in this context does "disable" not mean disable? Is it a bug or a design decision?

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Ok, I think I found it. What's up with two screen-locking settings?
[image: The lock setting that actually helped was under "screensaver"]

Comment: On my system, each time this binary (/usr/bin/xfce4-screensaver-preferences) is launched, it reset the setting of  ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-screensaver.xml so the only way is to edit the xml directly

Comment: I wonder, if you really need to disable "Enable Lock Screen"? Isn't it enough that you disable "Lock Screen with Screensaver" and "Lock Screen with System Sleep"? This settings dialog is for xfce4-screensaver, not for light-locker. Currently Xfce runs that screensaver eagerly so it you want to use another one, you have to uninstall  xfce4-screensaver package: https://gitlab.xfce.org/apps/xfce4-screensaver/-/issues/55

Comment: Exactly, there are two setting areas to disable it. Ridiculous.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to automate it or simply do it by command line, then you need to create or update 2 files:

`~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-screensaver.xml` with content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<channel name="xfce4-screensaver" version="1.0">
  <property name="saver" type="empty">
    <property name="mode" type="int" value="0"/>
    <property name="enabled" type="bool" value="false"/>
  </property>
  <property name="lock" type="empty">
    <property name="enabled" type="bool" value="false"/>
  </property>
</channel>
```

`~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-power-manager.xml` with content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<channel name="xfce4-power-manager" version="1.0">
  <property name="xfce4-power-manager" type="empty">
    <property name="power-button-action" type="empty"/>
    <property name="lock-screen-suspend-hibernate" type="empty"/>
    <property name="logind-handle-lid-switch" type="empty"/>
    <property name="blank-on-ac" type="int" value="0"/>
    <property name="blank-on-battery" type="int" value="0"/>
    <property name="dpms-enabled" type="bool" value="false"/>
    <property name="dpms-on-ac-sleep" type="empty"/>
    <property name="dpms-on-ac-off" type="empty"/>
    <property name="dpms-on-battery-sleep" type="empty"/>
    <property name="dpms-on-battery-off" type="empty"/>
    <property name="show-panel-label" type="empty"/>
    <property name="inactivity-sleep-mode-on-ac" type="empty"/>
    <property name="inactivity-sleep-mode-on-battery" type="empty"/>
    <property name="show-tray-icon" type="bool" value="false"/>
  </property>
</channel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `Hidden=true` to `/etc/xdg/autostart/light-locker.desktop`.  This will disable it for all users.

Command example:

`echo "Hidden=true" >> /etc/xdg/autostart/light-locker.desktop`

Tested on Xubuntu 20.04.